# Is owning casinos, or owning pornography business haram?

Tags: halal-haram, business, alcohol, gambling, pornography

I have read that gambling, pornography and alcohol among other things are haram. So would ownership in cam-girl industries and casinos, be considered haram also? Even if the person does not necessarily participate in these activities himself?

Comment: Yes any form of business that sells and encourages the prohibited is haram and the profits and earnings are themselves haram. Spiritually speaking it's dirty money. Causing and encouraging sin and benefitting from it is the issue.

Comment: It is one's responsibility to shut down such a business if he owns it

Answer (score 0):

Gambling, doing Fornication and drinking wine are haram. Any income arising from haram activities is also haram. This principle is codified in ahadith such as:

> نهى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم عن ثمن الكلب، وحلوان الكاهن، ومهر البغي
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) prohibited taking the price of a dog, the earnings of a soothsayer and the money earned by prostitution.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5346)</sup>

> إن الله ورسوله حرم بيع الخمر والميتة والخنزير والأصنام
>
> Allah and His Messenger made illegal the trade of alcohol, dead animals, pigs and idols.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2236)</sup>